# Find word and return whole line

Tags: php, search, return, file-get-contents

I use file_get_contents("http://www.mydomain.com"); to get the content. Then I need to search through it for a word and return the whole line where the word is found. Is this possible?

Comment: wait, are you trying to parse html?

Comment: What do you mean by "line"? A paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Iterate over each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php) in content.

Use `strpos` to check if line contains word that you are looking for.