# How to fetch youtube embed params from text?

Tags: php

How can I explode all Youtube embed values from a text using PHP? For example I have the text:

```
Fails: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ujwod-vqyqA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

More fails: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DYRTzXSYixQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

More the more: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/uLWqUW_U6dQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I want to use one of all videos embed for my facebook post, for example first video embed:

```
https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Ujwod-vqyqA/mqdefault.jpg
```

How can I do this? I tried with `strpos`, but this does not work.

Comment: i tried with "strpos" but it given only a number, where is embed. I think about "explode", but i dont know how it is possible.. it should be like this: get all "youtube.com/embed/*" and insert it in array and then i will be available to select on of them

Comment: What were your dev approaches? Posting your tried sniplet would help.

Comment: i have no idea how to do ir, thats why i am asking here. Like as i said, i tried with it:

 $youtube_look = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";
                $youtube_embed = strpos($article, $youtube_look);

but it gaven me only number

Comment: So basically something like this should do the job ?
`preg_match_all('/<iframe.*?src="(http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www.)youtube.com\/embed\/.*?)".*?>/i', file_get_contents('yourfile.txt'), $m);
print_r($m[1]);`

Comment: Take look into [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

Comment: yes i think so, but why you use *? and *?> ?

Comment: @user2304363 `.*` -> match everything, when you add a `?` to it (`.*?`) you will make it ungreedy (please search for this as there are so many examples/tutorials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = 'Fails: <iframe ...';

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $text) as $line) {
    if(!empty($line)) {
        $line = str_replace(array("iframe", "<", ">", '"'), null, $line);
        $values = explode(" ", trim($line));
        foreach($values as $value) {
            if(strpos($value, "=")) {
                $explode = explode("=", $value);
                $thisparams[$explode[0]] = $explode[1];
            }
        }
        $params[] = $thisparams;
    }
}
```

([Reference for preg_split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php))