# PHP Performing action on a variable line by line

Tags: php, line-by-line

I have a variable containing an html code and I want to perform an action of every line of the code:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');

#how i would like it to be (not real commands)
/*
$line = 1
$currentline = readline($html,$line)
line++
where $html is the variable that we want to read a line from
$line is the line number
and $currentline the contents

so if $line is 1 we get that $currentline is <html> or whatever

after that i perform things on that line and continue reading each line untill i read all the lines

*/

?>
```

I hope you understand what I mean/need. I’m very new to web based programming so I need a lot of explanation!

Please don’t use technical terms you think a PHP programmer should know because i do probably don't know what that is.

Comment: `file_get_html` should be used for DOM operations. What are you trying to do? Why do you process it line by line?

Comment: i was searching for a libary to do something,well i fixed it now that i knw i can use a diffrent command for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/) although one might argue about whether the answers are understandable for a beginner. This should do what you're looking for:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
// Skipped: Error checks

// Split $html into lines
$lines = explode("\n", $html);

// Iterate over all lines
foreach($lines as $line) {
  // Process $line
}

// Or get the 5th line
$fifth_line = $lines[4];

// Or iterate using an index
for($line = 0; $line < count($lines); $line++) {
  $theline = $lines[$line];
}
```

Comment: very interesting! i will take a look at it! im happy that you posted that :) but why explode ._. and what is foreach($lines as $line) all about?

Comment: the line with explode gives me an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: the function explode does exsist..but gives an error :) someone must have had fun while naming these commands @still_learning

Comment: This example works for me, there should not be any syntax errors. You can find answers to questions about `explode` and `foreach` at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.foreach.php), or just use [Google](https://google.com).

Comment: ahm @still_learning i do not know why foreach is not working.

Comment: wow @still_learning everything works now! i would like to thank you alot! please make this the final answer ^

Comment: That's your task, just check the green tick on the left.

Comment: did it @still_learning :) as you can see im new to SO - but one day i will be good  like you guys,like in every other language i tried to learn