# php- how to get specific line from a result?

Tags: php, curl

I want to get the line number 17 of some text using php. My code is as:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch); //stores text
```

Now a large number of text is stored in $result & I want to  get its line 17. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to consider performance, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `explode`. Refer [here](http://php.net/explode)

```
$res = explode("\n",$result);
echo $res[16];
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the line separator echoing the returned data from curl_exec(), then write the 17th array's element.

```
$res = curl_Exec($ch);
$res = explode("\n",$res);
echo $res[16]; // array starts from 0, so 16th is your 17th line.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = explode("\n", $result);
echo $lines[16];
```

but base on your result you may have to use "\r\n" Instead of "\n"