# PHP new line in string, how to add <p> tag

Tags: php, html, markup

So i have a PHP class value that has the following text inside

```
$classvalue =
  'line1 line1

  line2 line2

  line3 line3';
```

How can i convert this into proper HTML markup?

```
$classvalue =
  'line1 line1
  <br>
  line2 line2
  <br>
  line3 line3';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use nl2br to replace new line characters with br tag

```
$classvalue = nl2br($classvalue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

```
$classvalue = nl2br($classvalue);
```

Or, loop the new lines and replace blank lines with `<br>` (Covered in another [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php)).

Something like this (untested):

```
$output_lines = "";
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $classvalue) as $line){
    if (strlen($line) > 0) {
        $output_lines .= $line;
    } else {
        $output_lines .= "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go further and do

```
preg_replace("/[\r\n]/","<p>",$classvalue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below codes:

Either:

```
$return = preg_replace("/[\r\n]/","<p>",$classvalue);
// Regex contidion
```

Or:

```
$return = nl2br($classvalue);
// for new line separator
```