# Return multiple lines from a long string

Tags: php

I have a large string with multiple instances of header information. For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 01:43:13 GMT
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Location: http://www.google.com
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.7.9
Content-Length: 294
Connection: keep-alive
```

After "Location:", I want to save all the data from that line to an array. There might be 3 or 4 lines to save from a big block of text.

How could I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways you could do this.

#### Here's one way:

1. Split the text up at the point where `Location:` occurs
2. Split the result by new lines into an array

[Example:](https://eval.in/527805)

```
$text = substr($text, strpos($text, 'Location:'));
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
```

#### Here's another way:

1. Using regex, match `Location:` and everything after it
2. As above - split the result by new lines

[Example:](https://eval.in/527809)

```
preg_match_all('~(Location:.+)~s', $text, $output);
$output = explode(PHP_EOL, $output[0][0]);
```

Note: the `s` modifier means match newlines as part of the `.` - they will otherwise be ignored and new lines will terminate the capture.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way that works too I figured I would add in case it helps anyone:

```
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $bigString) as $line){
    if (strpos($line, 'Location') !== false) {
        // Do stuff with the line
    }
}
```

Source: [Iterate over each line in a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php)
There's a lot of helpful other ways in there too.

Comment: That'll only give you the lines that contain `Location`