# Read consecutive lines from file into key => value array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to convert a user/pass txt file to an array, I tried to do this with a foreach, explode, reg_split, but didn't get anything working in the right way.

Also a blank line should be skipped...

Example text file:

```
username1
password1
username2
password2

username3
password4
```

Example array:

```
array(
   $username1 => $password1,
   $username2 => $password2
)
```

Comment: This is fairly easy, what else have you tried?

Comment: Maybe this will help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1462759/3498950

Comment: I got my answer, I am just new to this so didn't really know what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the file into one array and then combine them into a new array with key-value pairs

```
$file = file("usernames.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$array = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($file) - 1; $i++){
  $array[$file[$i]] = $file[$i + 1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know about the file(arguments...)

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of pairs from the consecutive lines, then combine the column of keys with the column of values:

```
$chunks = array_chunk(
    file('userpass.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES),
    2
);
$users = array_combine(
    array_column($chunks, 0),
    array_column($chunks, 1)
);
```

**Explanation**

`$chunks` is an array of arrays: each inner array has two elements: #0 is the username (first line) and #1 is the password (second line). Using `file` to skip blank lines and remove trailing new-lines keeps this code simple, but not bullet-proof.

`$users` then is made by taking all the usernames (index `0` from all the inner arrays) and pointing them to all the passwords (index `1`).

You can accomplish the same with a loop over `$chunks`. However, I prefer this approach because all looping is handled inside the engine, where it is marginally more performant.

Answer (score -3):

I have to think on it, but I know you can read the file into an array using php's file() method.

```
$var = file("myFile.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```