# create php array from shell/bash output

Tags: php, bash, loops

I'm writing a php script that will execute a bash script on the server. The one thing that is absolutely required for this exercise is that we're using /var/tmp/count.sh to get my data.

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#filename: /var/tmp/count.sh
cat /etc/passwd | grep ':201:' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
#This command will spit out:
# user1
# user2
# user3
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/var/tmp/count.sh');
$sizeofme = sizeof($output);
echo "$output" . "\n" ;
echo "sizeofme = $sizeofme" . "\n" ;
// this spits out:
// user1
// user2
// user3
// sizeofme = 1
?>
```

How do I make a PHP array that contains 3 elements?
A PHP equivielant of the following bash for loop:

```
for i in ${output[@]; do
    newarray+=("$i")
done
```

Also, I noticed that if I do:

```
<?php
echo $output[0] . "\n" ;
echo $output[1] . "\n" ;
echo $output[2] . "\n" ;
echo $output[3] . "\n" ;
echo $output[4] . "\n" ;
echo $output[5] . "\n" ;
echo $output[6] . "\n" ;
echo $output[7] . "\n" ;
echo $output[8] . "\n" ;
echo $output[9] . "\n" ;
?>
```

I get:

```
u
s
e
r
1

u
s
e
r
2
```

...
so on and so forth. What am I overlooking?

Comment: The reason it's outputting like that is that you can treat a string as an array and get a single character back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PHP is treating the return as one contiguous string. Try the following

```
$data = explode("\n", $output);
var_dump($data);
```

That should give you the array you want

Comment: Related SO question: [how to iterate over a string line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php).  `explode` is more concise, +1

Comment: This is good. it's working like I expect. One issue though: the last entry is a newline:
`[3]=>
string(0) ""`
I'll work on trimming it out but thanks, this is good

Comment: `$data = explode("\n", $output);`
`$data2 = array_pop($data);`