# Wordpress textarea output new line to li

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea, html-lists

I have seen a few questions about this problem, but any answers haven't worked in my case.

I have textarea input in wordpress block, if someone will enter a text like this:

```
Lorem ipsum
Dolor sit
Amet
```

I need to get every new line as **`</li>`** tag, I was trying to do something like this:

```
$textAreaData = $PriceListItem[PriceListConfig::ITEMS_LIST_DESCRIPTION];
$textAreaDataList = "<li>" . str_replace("\n", "</li>\n<li>",trim($textAreaData, "\n"));
```

but it didn't work, can anyone please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

**Thank you**

Comment: Can you clarify "didn't work"? What was the value textAreaDataList after that second line ran?

Comment: You might want to check this....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over each line in a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php)

Comment: @DonR - After the first line the value was this: 
"Lorem ipsum&#13;&#10;Dolor sit&#13;&#10;Amet"
and the second line:
<li>Lorem ipsum&#13;&#10;Dolor sit&#13;&#10;Amet"

Comment: Something is HTML-encoding the CRLF values in the input before it gets to this code, so there is no newline, there is &#10; instead. You can try to track down why that's happening, or you can just replace the CRLF entities (&#13;&#10;) rather than \n (and append a final closing li tag, which you seem to have forgotten)