# Use scss on vue Single file component without cli or webpack

Tags: sass, vue-component, http-vue-loader

I'm developing a PHP based system where I cannot use webpack, NPM or the Vue CLI, my page has several components that are loaded on real-time using httpVueLoader, one example of such component is as follows

```
<template>
  <section class="Header-Top topHeader_mobile" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="HeadRight-Phone">
          <h1><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> {{ krakenBlock.contactNumber }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="HeadList">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" :title="krakenBlock.menuOpt1">{{ krakenBlock.menuOpt1 }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" :title="krakenBlock.menuOpt2">{{ krakenBlock.menuOpt2 }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" :title="krakenBlock.menuOpt3">{{ krakenBlock.menuOpt3 }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" :title="krakenBlock.menuOpt4">{{ krakenBlock.menuOpt4 }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" :title="krakenBlock.menuOpt5">{{ krakenBlock.menuOpt5 }}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  name: "headerVue1",
  data() {
    return {
      krakenBlock: {"menuOpt1":"WHY US","menuOpt2":"FAQS","menuOpt3":"Packing Boxes","menuOpt4":"Van Sizes","menuOpt5":"Payments","contactNumber":"01904 390 906"}
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style scope>
.HeadList {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  float: right;
}

.HeadList ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.HeadList ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

</style>
```

and My main page looks like this

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <headervue-1></headervue-1>
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          components: { 'headervue-1': httpVueLoader('https://192.168.0.104/modxMonster/renderedBlocks/headerVue1.vue'), }
          
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

So far everything is working like a charm, but today the client gave us a new requirement, they want to be able to use scss in the components, so the original styles from my first code sample should look like this:

```
.HeadList {
margin: 0;
padding: 12px 0;
float: right;
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 0 0 35px;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}
```

My initial guess is that I need to compile the scss section and generating a temp file to be passed to httpVueLoader but IM wondering if there a way to add the sass loader from CDN to have the vueLoader process this automatically?

Comment: You could maybe use https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/, but you should talk to your client about the tradeoffs between getting to use SCSS syntax and adding a 4.5Mb dependency.

Comment: totally, and this helps me justify why have it "on the fly" sint going to happen , we are currently looking at using https://scssphp.github.io/scssphp/ and just compile the scss on every file as part of our rendering process

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is facing the exact same requirement, this is what I did:

Starting from @jonrsharpe comment, I decided to take a look at different bundling options but each option out would lead to overhead to the final pages, so having the fact that I was already generating the component dynamically, decided just to parse the original .vue file, extract the scss portion, compile it with [scssPhp](https://scssphp.github.io/scssphp/) and the final code looks like this:

```
//Now we compile the SCSS
      $separator = "\n";
      $line = strtok($blockContent, $separator);
      $finalBlock = '';
      $styleSection = '';
      while ($line !== false) {
        $finalBlock .= $line . "\n";
        if (mb_strpos($line, '<style') === 0) {
          // Do while para halar el estilo...?
          do{
            $line = strtok( $separator );
            $styleSection .= (mb_strpos($line, '</style>') === 0) ? '' : $line;
          } while(!(mb_strpos($line, '</style>') === 0));
          //now se parse the style
          $compiledStyle =  $this->scss->compile($styleSection);
          $finalBlock .= $compiledStyle;
          $finalBlock .= "</style>";
        }
        $line = strtok( $separator );
      }
```

The inspiration to follow this path came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462720/iterate-over-each-line-in-a-string-in-php)